# How do I count the number of files in a directory using boost::filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost

I am given a boost::filesystem::path. Is there a fast way to get the number of files in the directory pointed to by the path?

Comment: Have you tried the simple_ls tutorial example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/example/simple_ls.cpp   How does that not meet your requirements?

Comment: Recursively or just in the one directory?

Comment: Have you read about the directory iterator? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-template-basic_directory_iterator

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ - Load all filename + count the number of files in a current directory + filter file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388402/c-load-all-filename-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-current-directory-filt)

Comment: @Gabe Not recursively, but that's also intereseting. @Krill I looked for something specific to boost but didn't find that one. I did a search and everything!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one-liner in Standard C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::filesystem;
    using namespace boost::lambda;

    path the_path( "/home/myhome" );

    int cnt = std::count_if(
        directory_iterator(the_path),
        directory_iterator(),
        static_cast<bool(*)(const path&)>(is_regular_file) );

    // a little explanation is required here,
    // we need to use static_cast to specify which version of
    // `is_regular_file` function we intend to use
    // and implicit conversion from `directory_entry` to the
    // `filesystem::path` will occur

    std::cout << cnt << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1. But, why not just use `int cnt = std::count_if(
        directory_iterator(the_path),
        directory_iterator(),
        static_cast<bool(*)(const path&)>(is_regular_file));`?

Comment: @xmllmx Good note. Of course, you can pass the `directory_entry` to the standalone `is_regular_file` function. And the call of `directory_entry::path()` will occur implicitly. I will update the answer.

Comment: one-liner in Standard C++???  Looks like a one liner in Boost which is not Standard C++.

Comment: @CraigB one-line is std::count_if. boost was used here only because OP asked about boost::filesystem::path.

Answer (score 11):

You can iterate over files in a directory with:

```
for(directory_iterator it(YourPath); it != directory_iterator(); ++it)
{
   // increment variable here
}
```

Or recursively:

```
for(recursive_directory_iterator it(YourPath); it != recursive_directory_iterator(); ++it)
{
   // increment variable here
}
```

You can find some simple examples [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 7):

```
directory_iterator begin(the_path), end;
int n = count_if(begin, end,
    [](const directory_entry & d) {
        return !is_directory(d.path());
});
```

Comment: This will count number of all elements, including sub-directories, not only files.

Comment: @Kirill: It wouldn't even have done that before I fixed it. :)

Comment: @Kirill: This? Yes. What I had before? No.

Comment: Oh.. The page hasn't refreshed :)

Comment: (ph=boost::phoenix) `ph::logical_not( ph::bind(&is_directory, ph::bind(&directory_entry::path, arg1) ) )` or so ought to do it