# Number of files in a folder

Tags: c++, animation, loading, blender

is there a specific way to directly get how many files there is in a given folder?
Like:

```
fol = openfolder("MyFolderPath");
int n = fol.getNumberOfFiles();
```

Or do I have to open the folder and iterate through all the files?

I'm reading obj files from Blender and trying to load in an animation. (lots of vertices, 1 file for each frame)

Also, for preformance... Is it bad to create your own animation class, using this method to store frames?

```
vector <vector <float>> frames;
vector <float> verticesForThisFrame;
verticesForThisFrame.push_back(readX());
verticesForThisFrame.push_back(readY());
verticesForThisFrame.push_back(readZ());
frames.push_back(verticesForThisFrame);
```

If it's very inefficient, what do you suggest I do?

EDIT: I use SDL to open a window, and OpenGL for graphics.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050298/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-boostfilesystem

Comment: There is no such system call provided by Operating system. SO you would have to open the directory and and read the number of files.

Comment: I suggest you split your question in two. Just looking at the title, no Blender expert will pay attention, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what framework/library you are using. You may be forced to open folder and iterate through its content, like

```
for( directory_iterator it(YourPath); it != directory_iterator(); ++it)
{
   // increment variable here
}
```

in case of boost, or get the files count like

```
QDir.count() // returns the total count of files and directories in the directory
             // use flags QDir::Filters with QDir::NoDotAndDotDot to exclude
             // . and ..
```

in case of Qt.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I forgot to write that. I use SDL to open a window. Then OpenGL for the graphics.