# replacement for findfirst() and findnext()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010-express

Is there any replacement for `findfirst()` and `findnext()`.
I am using `microsoft visual c++ 2010 express` and it doesn't support these functions neither the header file `<dir.h>` ?

I was looking to count the number of files in the directory using these functions but i am having a problem without these functions.

If there is no replacement of the mentioned functions is there any other way out. ? Some other functions ?

Comment: Have you checked: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ iammilind Actually this should have been the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As 'iammilind' said in the comments (probably worthy of an answer) - you can use the windows api's **FindFirstFile** and **FindNextFile** functions, you just have to fill up a struct and iterate through the latter until you reach an invalid handle. These functions *do* work on console, but you must include the 'Windows.h' header.

These functions do come with a couple of pitfalls however, and if you want your code to run on anything other than windows you're probably better off using another header/library (such as Boost::Filesystem, mentioned by vBx).

Also, this may be of help:
[C++ - Load all filename + count the number of files in a current directory + filter file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388402/c-load-all-filename-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-current-directory-filt)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) for that

Comment: ...and i can't find the function to find files.

Comment: read the tutorial http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html you will see how easy it is

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you can use: _findnext, _findnext64, _findnexti64, _wfindnext, _wfindnext64, _wfindnexti64

Answer (score 1):

If you use MinGW Developer Studio, this might help:

Assuming that you have the files in the dir you want to look will be:

```
sample1.txt
sample2.txt
sample3.txt
```

The code for the two files matching the pattern "s*" will be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<io.h>

int main()
{
    // the input pattern and output struct      
    char *pattern = "s*";
    struct _finddata_t fileinfo;

    // first file (sample1.txt)
    int x = _findfirst(pattern, &fileinfo);
    printf("%s" ,fileinfo.name);

    // next file (sample2.txt)
    _findnext(x, &fileinfo);
    printf("%s" ,fileinfo.name);

}
```